# How to use setTimeout in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, settimeout

In JavaScript:

```
setTimeout("document.write('example')", 200);
```

I want to know how I can do a `setTimeout` in Flash (AS3).

I know there's the `Timer()` class, but I want a more simple way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[setTimeout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout())** is exactly the same in flash as it is in JavaScript.  It can be found in the `flash.utils` package.

So:

```
import flash.utils.setTimeout;

setTimeout(trace,200,"hello world");
```

eg:

```
setTimeout(functionToCall, delayInMilliseconds, optionalArgument1, optionalArgument2, etc);
```

Comment: i worked in flash for 10 years, since mm owned it. It's silly the simple things you forget after a few years.